# Non-trivial connected semi-simple compact Lie group

Tags: group-theory, differential-geometry, terminology, lie-groups

This is a question about some terminology I'm not familiar with and was hoping to clarify.

I've seen it written that every "non-trivial connected semi-simple compact Lie group" contains a non-abelian Lie subgroup.

**Question:** But isn't $S^1$ such a group and yet abelian?

(E.g. This would make sense if "non-trivial" here refers to non-triviality of the Lie algebra; is this the standard usage?)

Comment: I apologize if I'm about to say something absurd (2 a.m. local time), but... $S^1$ is *not* semi-simple, no? It is abelian, so its Lie algebra is also abelian and the Killing form vanishes identically. For a connected Lie group, semi-simplicity should be equivalent to non-degeneracy of the Killing form (this is one of Cartan's criteria).

Comment: I see...the definition of simple also requires non-abelian according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Lie_group.

Comment: Semi-simple iff the Killing form K is non degenerate. Tr(adX adY)=K(X,Y). Abelian implies that the Killing form is 0 (beacause adX=0. So..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, $S^1$ is not semisimple. Unlike the case of groups, for Lie algebras the convention is that "simple" means "simple nonabelian."

(In my opinion this is such a useful convention it should be imported back into group theory; it would be very useful to have one word that means "simple nonabelian" in group theory also and it's annoying that there isn't one. Simple abelian and simple nonabelian groups behave very, very differently from each other, and this difference is so pronounced in the Lie case that terminology specific to it was unavoidable.)